# All-users application preferences on MAC OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, preferences

On MAC OS 10.8.x is it possible for an application to store global preferences (i.e. that applies to all users) without resorting to the use of a helper tool (such as SMJobBless) ?

I have tried to write to the app bundle, tried to find a location R/W by all users, without any luck on both attempts.

What else can I try ?

Comment: @trojanfoe Ideally, yes. But sandboxing, thought preferred, is not a requirement. So I will accept any solution, wether it works with sandboxing or not.

Comment: Just for explicitness: The entire app bundle should be presumed non-writable. When installed by the MAS, it is non-writable. When installed by an administrator, other users will find it non-writable. When delivered on a disk image, many users will simply drag it from there to their Dock; since the copy they're using is still on the disk image, which you generally ship compressed and read-only, the bundle on that image is non-writable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Leaving this answer here, but it may not really work for you, since you likely need privileged access to make the `CFPreferencesSetValue()` call. It's been several years since I've done one of these.*

If you don't need this to work with sandboxing, then the tool you want is the lower-level preferences interface, `CFPreferences`. Specifically, you can use `CFPreferencesSetValue()` and `CFPreferencesCopyValue()` along with `kCFPreferencesAnyUser`.

It is possible that this will work for sandboxed apps, but I haven't tried it. According to the [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) regarding "Managing Preferences Using Core Foundation":

> Writing outside the app domain is not possible for apps installed in a sandbox.

That hints that it's legal, since this is within the app domain. But it is quite possible that sandboxed apps will write that app domain preference within the per-user sandbox, so it won't actually work. You'd have to try it.

Comment: Writing to kCFPreferencesAnyUser does indeed require elevated privileges.